# Request dialog improvements

Tags: facebook

I want improve my request dialog multi selector.

This is the actual dialog request of my application:

[image]

But I have seen others request dialog here:

[image] this request dialog select automaticly 50 friends.

How I can do it?

This is my actual dialog code:

```
<script>
  FB.init({
    appId  : '290349771061160',
    frictionlessRequests: true,
  });

  function sendRequestToRecipients() {
    var user_ids = document.getElementsByName("user_ids")[0].value;
    FB.ui({method: 'apprequests',
      message: 'SELEZIONA 25 AMICI',
      to: user_ids, 
    }, requestCallback);
  }

  function sendRequestViaMultiFriendSelector() {
    FB.ui({method: 'apprequests',
      message: 'SELEZIONA 25 AMICI'
    }, requestCallback);
  }

  function requestCallback(response) {
    // Handle callback here
  }

  function requestCallback(response) {

    if((response != null) &&(response != false))
    {
      alert('ADESSO CLICCA IN ALTO A DESTRA SU MI PIACE');
    }
    // Handle callback here
  }
</script>
```

Comment: The Requests dialog has an optional `to` parameter, see docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/. It’ll take a list of comma-separated user ids.

Answer (score 0):

[Requests Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/) allow you to specify to which friends you want the request to be sent by specifying comma separated friends ids in `to` field (see [direct request](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/#direct_request)) (this is exactly what you can see on second picture).

The only difference between first and second is the `to` parameter which is empty for first one and filled for second.

Comment: Ok but in the second picture how the app insert the ids?

Comment: It may be something simple like [random N friends](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/a/8673443/155033) or something more complicated filtering of list of friends (from either Graph API `/me/friends?fields=id` or FQL)